# Translating single quote using trans

Tags: escaping, raku, quoting

I can't find a way to translate using [`trans`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/trans) a single quote to a escaped single quote:

```perl6
say ($ = "'well done'").=trans("'" => "\\\'" ) ;# OUTPUT: «\well done\␤»
say ($ = "'well done'").=trans(<'> => Q [\'] ) ;# OUTPUT: «\well done\␤»
say ($ = "'well done'").=trans("'" => q"\\\'" );# OUTPUT: «\well done\␤»
```

There's probably a workaround using split or any number of other things, including `subst`. In principle, the first one actually produces `\'`, which is what I've been looking for. Maybe doubling up the scapes will help?

Comment: Hmm. An opportunity to try out [a doc I wrote on trans about a month ago](https://gist.github.com/raiph/a9d58825662b5cf2da2cc550cb3c6989). I'll post this comment then go read it and see if I understand it and if it provides insight into your question... :)

Comment: OK. I see a natural solution. (Make matcher and replacer be lists.) And now I see Liz has suggested that. Nice to know I could get to the answer fairly quickly. :)

Comment: You might be better off using a global `subst` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this is a gotcha with `trans`, but you actually need to specify a "from" list and a "to" list, otherwise it will just interpret the left side as a range of graphemes to be translated into the other range of graphemes:

```
say "'well done'".trans("abcde" => "vwxyz" );  # OUTPUT: 'wzll yonz'
```

If you create a list of strings to convert from one to the other, you get the desired result:

```
say "'well done'".trans(["'"] => ["\\'"] )  # OUTPUT: \'well done\'
```